# Azure: Can I mirror a deployment slot

Tags: azure, azure-deployment, azure-deployment-slots

After the staging deployment slot has been swapped to production, I know have the old production code sitting in the staging slot. This is fine in case I need to roll back. However, after a while, I know there are no problems.

It seems that the process is not that I should update the staging slot with the latest code in order to make it mirror the production slot. This can be a hassle to upload all over again.

Can I mirror the files from the production slot back to the staging slot so that they are in sync again?

Comment: `However, after a while, I know there are no problems.`. Really?

Comment: @miparnisari It's not a very complicated site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure you can do this anyway. But you **shouldn't**.

Do you work on production for staging ?

I suggest you to use [Continuous integration in Azure using Kudu](http://www.codetails.com/2015/05/13/continuous-integration-in-azure-using-kudu/)

Then you will just click **Sync** .

Comment: Not doing it seems like the prevailing view. Happy to accept that and move on.